Do the laws of vector addition and scalar multiplication generalize to all vector spaces?
The traditional way to introduce vectors is by talking of them as arrows. Then, the laws of vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined as follows:
$\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a_1+b_1\\a_2+b_2\\a_3+b_3\end{bmatrix}$
$r\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ra_1\\ra_2\\ra_3\end{bmatrix}$
These laws can then be shown to be consistent with the arrow interpretation of a vector. Doing tip to tail vector addition is consistent with adding the distance moved in each direction. Additionally, the Pythagorean theorem can be used to show consistency between scalar multiplication by $r$ and stretching the arrow's length by $r$.
So, these two definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication essentially define what a vector is. However, when defining a vector space, the properties of commutativity, associativity, etc. are used. These properties are true for "arrows in space" but they arise from the definitions of vector and scalar multiplication. They don't define vectors. So, my questions are the following:
Why didn't we just use the definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication as axioms for vector spaces? Are there ways to redefine the notion of vector addition and scalar multiplication while also satisfying the axioms of a vector space? If yes, wouldn't be it wrong to say that vectors obey the addition and scalar multiplication rules since vectors are just elements of a vector space?

What exactly do you mean by the laws of vector addition and scalar multiplication?  Part of the definition of a vector space defines what these things even mean, but it seems that you have something more specific in mind.

@user806050 I'm referring to the two equations as laws of vector addition and scalar multiplication. The vector space axioms require only that these operations be defined such that they are commutative, associative, etc. So, is there an alternative way to formulate these two laws while satisfying the vector space axioms?

I think the bigger issue lies one step before the definition of vector addition and scalar multiplication: You seem to view vectors as lists of numbers. But this isn't so.
For instance, consider the set of all functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. It is often called $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$. We can define $f+g$ as the function sending $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$ and $r\cdot f$ as the function sending $x\mapsto r\cdot f(x)$. $(\mathbb R^\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space with the zero function as its zero element. And it has nothing to do with arrows or lists of numbers (unless you view functions on the reals als uncountable lists...).
If you want something more exotic: Consider the usual set $\mathbb R^3$ you are familiar with. Now let's define
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2\\
b_3
\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}
\tan(\arctan(a_1)+\arctan(b_1))\\
\tan(\arctan(a_2)+\arctan(b_2))\\
\tan(\arctan(a_3)+\arctan(b_3))
\end{pmatrix}\\
r\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3
\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}
\tan(r\arctan(a_1))\\
\tan(r\arctan(a_2))\\
\tan(r\arctan(a_3))
\end{pmatrix}$$
$\mathbb R^3$ with these exotic sums and multiples forms a vector space according to the definition (try proving it!). The trick works the same with any injective function $f$ on the reals replacing $\arctan$ and its inverse replacing $\tan$.
The point of abstract linear algebra is that we don't necessarily work in the usually known spaces, but in any space where some weirdly (up to interpretation) defined addition and multiplication exists, as long as it obeys the axioms.

So is it technically wrong to say that vectors follow the laws of vector addition and scalar multiplication as prescribed in my question?

As prescribed in your question, yes it's wrong. Although when you talk about the "laws of vector addition", I personally would assume you meant the axioms and not what you wrote.

Let $V$ be a set with a map $+:V\times V\to V$ and $\cdot : F\times V\to V$ for a field $F$. $V$ is called an $n$-dimensional vector space if it is linearly isomorphic to the space of $n$-arrows $F^n$. Your definition only works for finite-dimensional vector spaces, however.
